# Do you necessarily have to use a method to use 'this' of an object

Tags: javascript, this

Why does `this` in `x.prop2` returns `Undefined` but it works when trying to use it in `x.prop3` through a method?

I have been told it's because of difference of scope between `prop2` and `prop3`, but can anyone explain to me in detail the reason for that behavior?

```js
let x = {
  prop1: 10,
  prop2: this.prop1,
  prop3: function () {
    return this.prop1
  }
};

console.log(x.prop2) // undefined
console.log(x.prop3()) // 10
```

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by how the **function** it appears within is called. (With some exceptions, notably arrow functions).

Comment: The line `prop2: this.prop1` is within the global scope (not within a function). The line `return this.prop1` is within the scope of the anonymous function that was assigned to `prop3` which is invoked with `x` as `this` in the line `console.log(x.prop3())`.